# Secure encryption for a one-way transaction in Node.js

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptography

I've got some data that's going to be sent over a websocket. A lot of different devices are validating the packages contents, like a blockchain, so I can't send the event directly to the receiver of the data. However, I don't want the other people to read the contents of the message.

Is there a secure way to encrypt the data so that only the other person can read it?

The only data the first user has access to is the other person's username.

I was thinking about using RSA encryption using a method something like [this](https://www.sohamkamani.com/nodejs/rsa-encryption/), but I don't know how to get the private key to the other person. I would prefer if I didn't have to send a direct message to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: Without a "handshake" or a common secret on both sides (you and the other person) there is no way for encrpytion/decrpytion scenario.

Comment: @Marc thanks for your input! I'll accept that as the answer if you could elaborate a bit. Thanks so much

Comment: In the (asnc?) cryptography you and your partner have to agree on a common thing to exchange/sign stuff for each other. Since you cant/want to share a secret there is no way to sign data from parties, since your opposite dont know with what he should sign his data that you can decpryt it. Its a bit hard for me to explain it in english. But the article you linked explains it very well. On the encrypt and decrypt site you need a key/passprase. This must be on both sites the same.

Comment: @Marc thanks for that explanation! That really helped me. :)

Comment: If this system should work not only for two participants but for many in exactly the same way, then you're looking for [Identity-based encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity-based_encryption)